# Quality gate widget issue in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-dashboard

I have configured a quality gate widget with project key and api link in Azure dashboards.
But this doesn't work and my quality widget shows a red cross mark.
Could someone help what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you looked at [embedding the SQ badges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370061/598141) directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can reproduce this issue. According to the error message, we recommend that you raise a new issue [here](https://github.com/yuriburger/quality-gate-widget/issues/1).

In addition, it seems that this is a [known issue](https://github.com/yuriburger/quality-gate-widget/issues/1) on extension `Quality Gate Widget`, you could follow this ticket for the latest news.

[image]

**Update1**

It seems that we cannot get sonar report in Azure dashboards, we could check the report in the build summary page Extensions tab, please check the pic below. And also we could click the link to get the detail info.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou..looks like the developer hasn't fixed the issues from long back..Is there any other way where we can get sonar report in Azure dashboards?

Comment: Hi @priya, We cannot get sonar report in Azure dashboards now. I have updated the answer, please check it.  If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it. Thanks.